# Unable to refresh acordion in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The webpage initially would have a button. Upon clicking it, it adds two accordions who's headings are stored in a list, which is a part of click event handling function. The button, should create new accordions reading from the same list, irrespective the number of times it's clicked.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#updateAccordion").click(function() {
      new_array = ['new_item1', 'new_item2']
      $("#mainAccordion").empty();
      var accordion_data = ''
      for (var i = 0; i < new_array.length; i++) {
        accordion_data += '<h3><a href="#">' + new_array[i] + '</a></h3><div class="accordion">'
        accordion_data += '</div>'
      }

      $("#mainAccordion").append(accordion_data)
      $(".accordion").accordion({
        heightStyle: 'content',
        active: false,
        collapsible: true
      });
    });
  });

</script>
<button id="updateAccordion">Apply</button>

<div class="accordion" id="mainAccordion">
</div>
```

This works as expected the first time. However, upon clicking it again, it doesn't create any accordions. It just creates to links.

The fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zLbd0e05/4/).

Comment: You are actually removing previously added accordin and adding them again
`$("#mainAccordion").empty();`

Comment: Yes.. that is what I want to do. But for some reason "adding them again" isn't happening as expected

Comment: @Anvith, See my answer and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Anvith, if it full fill your requirement then you can also give me an upvote. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problem found in your program.

- You didn't place `;` at the end of your expression.e.g `var accordion_data = ''`.
- If you want to use jquery accordion then you should use `jquery.js`, `jquery-ui.js` and `jquery-ui.css` these libs.
- To update your accordion you should first destroy it and re-initiate it with accordion options.

Follow the code below, and this is perfectly working.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script type="text/javascript">



$(function(){
    $('#mainAccordion').accordion({
        heightStyle: 'content',
        active: false,
        collapsible: true
    });
});
  
  
  $(function(){
      $("#updateAccordion").click(function() {
      var new_array = ['new_item1', 'new_item2'];
      $("#mainAccordion").empty();
      var accordion_data = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < new_array.length; i++) {
         accordion_data += '<h3><a href="#">' + new_array[i] + '</a></h3><div class="accordion"><p>this is some text</p></div>';
      }
      var option = {
       heightStyle: 'content',
       active: false,
       collapsible: true
      };

      $("#mainAccordion").append(accordion_data);
      $("#mainAccordion").accordion('destroy').accordion(option);
      
    });
  });
    



</script>
<button id="updateAccordion">Apply</button>
<div id="mainAccordion" class="accordion">
    
 <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>

    <div>
        <p>Section 1 Content</p>
    </div>
    
 <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
 <div>
        <p>Section 2 Content
    </div>
    
 <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
 <div>
        <p>Section 3 Content</p>
    </div>
    
 <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
 <div>
        <p>Section 4 Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```